# Unit testing RavenDb queries

Tags: ravendb

Is there a sensible way to stub/mock the results of a call to `IDocumentSession.Query()`?

I have a command where I'd like to verify that methods are called on objects (that is the "unit" being tested is the command NOT the objects the command orchestrates).  I can't save Mock objects (via RhinoMocks) into an embedded db instance, so at the moment and being forced to verify state on the objects being called, rather than just verifying that the correct methods have been called.

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are better of when using `EmbeddableDocumentStore { RunInMemory = true}` for unit testing.
That said, `IDocumentSession` should be *very* easy to mock.

Comment: Thanks Ayende, the problem is using an EmbeddedDocumentStore means I have to use real objects not mocks.  IDocumentSession is indeed very easy to mock, IRavenQueryable not so much.

Comment: @mattcole What is wrong with using `EmbeddableDocumentStore { RunInMemory = true }` ?? Why do you want to mock out the `IDocumentSession`? Yes.. running `EmbeddableDocumentStore` is slightly slower than a mocked one .. but I'm pretty sure that *one* of the main reasons the `EmbeddableDocumentStore` was created, was for unit testing.

Comment: I'm fighting 2 things in my head at the moment: 1. Don't tell me not to mock - it is a bad smell to me that I can't. 2. When using the EmbeddableDocumentStore, the tests are running really slow - so I would like to mock!